# Entity of different type with a lot of fields - what is best approach to model it?

Tags: java, oop

This topic is a little bit more complicated then in a title.
Let's assume that we want to model an entity. This is something like KYC informations (name,surname, address etc). I could model this in simple way in one class like:

```
public class KYCInfo {

    private KYCInfoType type;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Address personalAddress;
    private Address buisnessAddress;
    private String country;
    private String state;

    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private String personalIdNumber;
}
```

As you see in code above, this KYC can be of different type. Actually two values can be in that type - buisness and individual. For business, buisnessAddress field is required, for individual personalIdNumber is required. Additionaly some of this fields will be required depending on country field. `State` field is for US but not for European countries. Placing all of this fields in one class seems to be inappropriate - every instance, depending on field would have a lot of null values. I could create separate classes for `BuisnessKYCInfo` and `IndividualKYCInfo` for example. But then I would have some duplications in fields (lets say that `firstName`,`lastName` and some other fields are the same for both classes). I could create some abstraction with common fields. Like :

```
public abstract class KYCInfo {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

Now imagine that this is a simple DTO class and in some moment i process it somehow in a method `processKYCInfo()`. When I have two classes BuisnessKYCInfo`and`IndividualKYCInfo``` then I would need to have two methods 
``processKYCInfo(BuisnessKYCInfo kycInfo) ``` and `processKYCInfo(IndividualKYCInfo kycInfo)`. This method will do the same operation, but will collect info from different fields. Now imagine, that you have more type than individual or buissness. Or as i wrote before, additional 'type' comes in like `country`. Now I would need to have 25 countries, some of them have fields specific only for that country. With the same approach like before I would have 25 methods doing almost the same. This also seems to be inappropriate. What other option do I have to model this ? Maybe some data structure, maybe some Map ? What is best approach of doing this ? How can I do it in more generic way ?

Comment: You're supposed to ask _one_ specific question at a time. This is way too broad and too many questions. A general comment, I would separate data and business logic and look for different design solutions for them

Comment: You are right, this is a really broad question, but it's a question like 'what design pattern would you use in that situation'.  If no here, where else should I look for other programmers opinion ?

Comment: What's `KYCInfo`'s public API ?

Comment: In this case KYCInfo would be more like DTO object, so getters, setters are public

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

**Following is the data structure I'll use:-**

```
  public class KYCInfo {
      private KYCInfoType type;
      private Map<String, String> name;
      private Map<String, String> address;
      private String country;
      private String state;
      private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
      private String personalIdNumber;
      public KYCInfo(){
          name = new HashMap<>();
          address = new HashMap<>();
  }
```

So what is the advantage of this approach:-

- Instead of creating multiple same type of attributes, create a family. e.g. name will be the family for 'firstName', 'middleName', 'lastName'. The  pair will be like <'firstName','Bob'> ,<'lastName','Marley'> etc. In this way you can have either of them or all of them.
- Similarly for other attributes like address. The  pair can be like <'personalAddress','some value'> , <'buisnessAddress','some value'>
- Each record can have their own categories for a family.

Comment: what about other fields, let's say personalIdNumber. It is valid field only for Individuals. Idea with maps is good when you have multiple variation of the same object like personalAddress buisnessAddress. But maybe the whole  object could bee implemented as Map ?

Comment: Yeah you are right about Map for multiple variation of the same object . Yeah I think that every attributes can be considered as family and inside that you can have the members. This approach will solve your problem of having multiple processing methods. Hope this helps